# What does this mean?

Tags: cgminer

```
connected to stratum.bitcoin.cz diff 1 with stratum as user xxxxxxxworker1
block f9aa8c61...Diff 4.25 started [20:26:18] Best share 0
Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
```

I just started doing this and it looks like I'm doing it wrong. Am I?

Comment: There's no error in that.

Comment: If you want to keep this question, you should give it a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

This seems normal. Wait 10 minutes and see if theres some "Yay!!!" messages

Comment: Its been like this for a couple days but no YAY !

Comment: That is not normal. Hmm what device are you using? Could it just be too slow?